# Not able to print an array in python after appending values to it

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop

[<**main**.Bsc_info instance at 0x00000000041D5C08>]

this is what i get in console when i try to print an array in python.

newbiee to python . 
thankyou for help in advance :-)

Comment: What is the question? It looks like you have an array with one element which is an instance of `class Bsc_info`.

Comment: @CristiFati Yes sir/mam ,  i have one element which is an instance of `class Bsc_info` which i have appended it into an array (just one of many elements) . when i print the array i get the above mentioned output. is there a way to print the array as it is.   _Thankyou:-)_